# python - return returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I wrote a function which gets two numbers and an operation (string) and returns the result of the two numbers with the given operation. For example calculate_matehamatical_expression(5,6,'+') should return 11. I divide the the assignment to little functions, but when I call these little function it always returns None. Can someone explain to me why that happens? This is the Code I wrote:

```
def mathematical_sum(num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2

def mathematical_difference(num1,num2):
    return num1 - num2

def mathematical_product(num1,num2):
    return num1 * num2

def mathematical_division(num1,num2):
    if num2 != 0:
        return num1 / num2
    else:
        return None

def operation_error(operation):
    if operation != "+" or operation != "-" or operation != "*" or operation != "/":
        return None




def calculate_mathematical_expression(num1,num2,operation):
    if operation == "+":
        mathematical_sum(num1,num2)
    elif operation == "-":
        mathematical_difference(num1,num2)
    elif operation == "*":
        mathematical_product(num1,num2)
    elif operation == "/":
        mathematical_division(num1,num2)
    else:
        operation_error(operation)
```

Comment: in `calculate_mathematical_expression` you're not doing anything with the returned values. And `operation_error` does nothing.

Comment: `return` or `return None` or no `return` statement at all do the same thing: `return None`.

Comment: You guys are right! Thank you! It's just that I was told to divide to little functions and then build the bigger one that's why it came like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return again inside `calculate_mathematical_expression`, e.g.:

```
def calculate_mathematical_expression(num1,num2,operation):
    if operation == "+":
        return mathematical_sum(num1,num2)
```

The return in `mathematical_sum` doesn't affect the function it's being called from.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Although I do not understand why it doesn't affect. Is there an explanaton to that? Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesCarmichael If the inner return made the outer function return, you wouldn't be able to break functions up easily at all. `x = mathematical_sum(...)` would end the function `calculate_mathematical_expression` before you could do anything with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to `return`

**When you `return` from a function, it only returns to the function that called it.** So when you `return` in `mathematical_sum()`, the value is returned to `calculate_mathematical_expression()` & you need to return again from this function, like this:

```
if operation == "+":
    return mathematical_sum(num1,num2)
elif operation == "-":
    return mathematical_difference(num1,num2)
elif operation == "*":
    return mathematical_product(num1,num2)
elif operation == "/":
    return mathematical_division(num1,num2)
else:
    return operation_error(operation)
```

...otherwise `calculate_mathematical_expression()` returns `None`.

---

#### `operation_error()` does not work

- **Use `and` instead of `or`.** Otherwise your condition will always be `True`
- **Return a boolean, not `None`.** Here, your function always return `None`

Example:

```
def operation_error(operation):
    return operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"
```

---

#### You don't need `operation_error()`

Since you have a condition for each operator, you don't need the `operation_error()` function, you can directly do this:

```
else:
    return None
```

...or even remove the `else` statement and let `calculate_mathematical_expression()` automatically return `None` when reaching its end.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculate_mathematical_expression function is not returning anything. Try following code:

```
def calculate_mathematical_expression(num1,num2,operation):
    if operation == "+":
        return mathematical_sum(num1,num2)
    elif operation == "-":
        return mathematical_difference(num1,num2)
    elif operation == "*":
        return mathematical_product(num1,num2)
    elif operation == "/":
        return mathematical_division(num1,num2)
    else:
        return operation_error(operation)
```